# AWS Host receives traffic, but Apache is slow to respond to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4

I have a vhost listening on port 443.
Through TCPDump I know that the host itself is receiving the request from the browser, and as far as I can work out the connection is ok, see sample dump output:

```
12:26:11.238593 IP BROWSER.34156 > HOST.https: Flags [P.], seq 1:518, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 2402991565 ecr 17262140], length517
12:26:11.238617 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.34156: Flags [.], ack 518, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 17262185 ecr 2402991565], length 0
12:26:11.240109 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.34156: Flags [P.], seq 1:1937, ack 518, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 17262186 ecr 2402991565], length 1936
12:26:11.257629 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.32718: Flags [S.], seq 994200905, ack 3372729358, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 17262204ecr 2402986264,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:26:11.257640 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.mtrgtrans: Flags [S.], seq 3850405604, ack 538070284, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 17262204 ecr 2402951572,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:26:11.267663 IP BROWSER.34156 > HOST.https: Flags [.], ack 1937, win 65, options [nop,nop,TS val 2402991594 ecr 17262186], length 0
12:26:11.296038 IP BROWSER.34156 > HOST.https: Flags [F.], seq 518, ack 1937, win 65, options [nop,nop,TS val 2402991623 ecr 17262186], length 0
12:26:11.296177 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.34156: Flags [F.], seq 1937, ack 519, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 17262242 ecr 2402991623], length 0
12:26:11.322100 IP BROWSER.34156 > HOST.https: Flags [.], ack 1938, win 65, options [nop,nop,TS val 2402991648 ecr 17262242], length 0
12:26:12.657696 IP HOST.https > BROWSER.24068: Flags [S.], seq 3364630219, ack 1425775294, win 26847, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 17263604 ecr 1334034660,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:26:13.094538 IP BROWSER.32718 > HOST.https: Flags [S], seq 3372729357, win 29200, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 2402993424 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
```

However the trouble is that while the host receives the traffic, Apache doesn't seem to immediately respond to it. I am not 100% certain that the firewall this vhost sits behind isn't blocking the response conditionally, however I believe there is a problem with Apache to a degree, as I see nothing in the access log during the time periods that the browser struggles to make a connection.
When it finally does make the connection, traffic shows up in the access log.

It is also potentially worth noting that this host has two networking interfaces, with the server name registered as a dns record pointing to the eth0 interface. Nothing comes out of the eth1 interface until the connection is established and working.

Vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      redacted
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   redacted

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} TRACE
    RewriteRule ^ "-" [F,L,R=405]
    LogLevel info

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader unset REMOTE_USER
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://myhost/auth/realms/REALMREDACTED/.well-known/openid-configuration
    OIDCRedirectURI https://myhost/redirect
    OIDCCryptoPassphrase redacted
    OIDCClientID apache
    OIDCClientSecret redacted
    OIDCProviderTokenEndpointAuth client_secret_basic
    OIDCRemoteUserClaim preferred_username
    OIDCScope "openid email profile"
    OIDCSessionType server-cache
    OIDCSSLValidateServer off
        OIDCInfoHook userinfo

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName myhost

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /home
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this wasn't actually a problem with Apache.

Without divulging too much information about the system being worked with, the Apache instance sat behind a firewall instance which NAT'd to the Apache instance, and there was an AWS Network ACL between them.

Because we assumed this was this was a linux instance and we looked to lock down traffic, the ACL on the firewall had a chance to reject the return traffic from Apache, as the NATting preserved the port used to open the connection.

Since we assumed linux [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), but test machines used windows, if the windows machine opened a connection listening on a port < 32768, then when Apache would try to respond but AWS would drop the packet due to the ACL rule and result in the time out. The key here is Windows traditionally uses ports 1025 - 5000 for ephemeral ports, though [newer versions of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/929851/the-default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcp-ip-has-changed-in-windows-vista) use the IANA default range of 49152 to 65535.

This is why our TCPDump would suggest traffic was being received just fine, but the TCP handshake would not complete if using a "low" port.